# How can I pass an existing object into Puppeteer's page.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using a nice logging library in node, which writes a log message with a simple `logger.debug("Message")` method.

I can't figure out how to pass the logger object into `page.evaluate` so I can use it in there.

I explored `page.exposeFunction` but that seems to be for an anonymous function that is created inline. I want to pass the existing logger object that I already have instantiated.

I also tried just adding the whole thing as to the page object, i.e. `page.logger = logger`, but no luck.

What can I do?

Comment: I think this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/624201). You are trying to call the logger from within the browser, you don't really want to pass `logger` over, right?

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes, you might be right. The goal is that I can write logging messages to node.js from anywhere in my code, including inside page.evaluate() functions (which can be long and do a lot of lifting that I want to log).

Comment: Then you have to use `exposeFunction`. Check out @vsemozhetbyt answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try some variants.

1. If `logger.debug()` does not need `logger` as its `this`, this may suffice:

```js
await page.exposeFunction('loggerDebug', logger.debug);
```

2. If `logger.debug()` needs `logger` as its `this`, this may suffice:

```
await page.exposeFunction('loggerDebug', logger.debug.bind(logger));
```

3. And you can try a wrapper:

```js
await page.exposeFunction('loggerDebug', (msg) => { logger.debug(msg); });
```

All variants can be used via:

```js
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  // ...
  window.loggerDebug("Message");
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I never would have figured this out on my own-- but your examples are great, and #2 works perfectly. Learned something new today...

Comment: Thank you! You can read a bit more about method extraction here: http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch17.html#_pitfall_losing_this_when_extracting_a_method ("Pitfall: Losing this When Extracting a Method")